# Convert nested text to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Say for example I have the following code:

```
<a onclick="afunction()">1</a>
```

And the variable

```
var output;
```

I want the function from clicking the nested text inside the <a> tag (in this example, the number 1) to make that text become what the variable of output equals. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so using `textContent`

```
<a id="myLink">1</a>
```

JS:

```
var output = 'New Text Content';
var link = document.getElementById('myLink');
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.textContent = output;
});
```

Comment: Even if elmeent's content is pure text, `.innerHTML` is still preferred over `.textContent` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Well, my answer isn't considering browser compatibility, hence the use of only `addEventListener`.

Comment: I've had long discussions on whether we should provide compatibility information in your answers. The majority is for.

Comment: If I were to provide a fully compatible answer, it would make the answer complicated and less informational, compatibility is something that everyone needs to learn about themselves.

Comment: @Connor Compatibility should be included along side any 'simple' example that needs that kind of consideration.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='#' onclick='this.innerHTML = doSomething();' >1</a>

window.doSomething = function ()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

I'm sure you don't need a jsfiddle but here it is anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/j9LaT/

The idea is to change the context of the caller this (in your case that element)

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
function afunction()
{
    var output='New Text';
    event.target.innerHTML=output;
}
```